# How to loop back the microphone entry directly to speakers on linux?

Tags: linux, raspbian

I would like to loop back a USB microphone entry to an audio output on linux (raspbian OS).

When i speak into the microphone, i would like to immediatly hear it to the speakers, with minimal delay.

I haven't found any open source project that do it.

Do you you know how to do it, by programming, reading writing on devices, or if there is a small piece of OSS that can do it ?

Thanks

Loïc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it through `arecord | aplay` pipeline in linux.

Check the sound card and device number of usb device through `aplay -l` (***for Playback***) and `arecord -l` (***for Capture***).

Then run the below command to concurrently recording and playback:

```
arecord -Dhw:<card_num>,<device_num> -c <channel_number> –f <format> -r <sample_rate> | aplay -Dhw:<card_num>,<device_num>
```

You can add more parameter if required for playback or capture.

Comment: This work fine if format is the same for capture and playback. For a raspberry pi for exemple, format is different for the mic and the jack output, and are incopatible. Do you know how to convert the format ?

Comment: You can use the [alsa plugins](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html). Like `arecord -Dplughw:<card_number>,<device_num>`

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working ! There is a smal delay, but with better hardware, i think it can be reduced. And most important, i have understood how it works :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the command

```
pacmd load-module module-loopback latency_msec=5
```

Comment: e.g. start a 3 seconds delayed loopback mode with `pacmd load-module module-loopback latency_msec=3000`, and stop the loopback afterwards with `pacmd unload-module module-loopback`. Did you know you can start _multiple_ loopbacks at the _same_ time, e.g. with _different_ latency_msec's, in parallel? This is big fun!

Comment: Prefer this one over `arecord | aplay` pipeline.